# How to add different font awesome icons in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, font-awesome, webpack-2

I am modeling an app section to display three different tabs with three different Font Awesome icons. So far, the tabs are set in the following way and the application shows only one icon in tab:

```
   <div class="tab">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
           <li v-for="(tab,index) in tabs" :class="{active : curentTab===index}" 
            @click="curentTab=index">
         <a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" style="width:auto" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{tab}}
         </a></li>
      </ul>

 </div>
```

Here follows the Vue application snippet to model the tabs.

```
   <script>
   data() {
    return {
      curentTab:0,
      tabs:['Tab1','Tab2 ','Tab3']
    }
  }
  </script>
```

How can I show different icons for different tabs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: according to your snippet it seems that the only `active` `li` will be the one with `index = 0` because of `curentTab` being set to `0`. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @P3trur0 yes active index=0,but i want to set each index value with one icon

Comment: Here on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLjQaw) I tried to reproduce your source code and actually I see three icons as expected.

Comment: @P3trur0 here show three same icon,but i want different icon for diferent tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render each tab with its specific icon you could modify your data model by introducing a different icon for each tab. For example, like this:

```
tabs:[
  {label: 'Tab1', icon:'smile'},
  {label: 'Tab2', icon:'bullhorn'},
  {label: 'Tab3', icon:'heart'}
]
```

Also, you have to modify your `template` by binding the `i` CSS class accordingly. To do so, you can:

1. introduce a Vue method returning the proper CSS class corresponding to the FontAwesome one, e.g.:

```
    methods: {
         faClass(icon) {
            return `fa fa-${icon}`;
          }
        }
```

2. invoke this new method in your `template`, like this:

```html
<i :class="[faClass(tab.icon)]" style="width:auto" aria-hidden="true">
```

Here you can see how `class` is now bound through Vue itself.

---

So, going back to your example, you will have:

**HTML template**

```
<div id='app'>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
           <li v-for="(tab,index) in tabs" :class="{active : curentTab===index}" 
            @click="curentTab=index">
         <a href="#">
       <i :class="[faClass(tab.icon)]" 
           style="width:auto" 
           aria-hidden="true"></i> {{tab.label}}
         </a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**Vue instance**

```
    ...
    data: function() {
       return {
        curentTab:0,
        tabs:[
         {label: 'Tab1', icon:'smile'},
         {label: 'Tab2', icon:'bullhorn'},
         {label: 'Tab3', icon:'heart'}
       ]
      }
     },
      methods: {
        faClass(icon) {
          return 'fa fa-'+icon;
        }
      }
    ...
```

Check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gzjwxp) to see it in action.

Comment: showing this error The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions